# System Requirement in Windows App Development

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit OS. Planning to develop Windows Mobile Apps.
I have Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: This is not a question that is suited for SO.

Answer (score 1):

No.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx#windows) for the system requirements; 4GB is required.